# Hp spectre 14 ea000 audio fix: Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

There has been a lot of questions on the few solutions to hp spectre 14 ea000 audio issues and the best temporary fix i got for my laptop (hp spectre 14: 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1165G7) has been the amp pin fix below;

#!/bin/bash

```
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x01 SET_GPIO_DIR 0x01
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x01 SET_GPIO_MASK 0x01
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x01 SET_GPIO_DATA 0x01
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x01 SET_GPIO_DATA 0x00
```

My audio sound card is alc245.
This was made into a script and ran everytime i needed audio from any application.
The side issue here is, the audio source must be active: e.g a movie or audio must be playing in the background before the script will activate the sound audio.
And immediately the sound stops playing, the audio sound source it disable again.
This cycle has to be repeated again to have audio and is quite frustrating.

The solution i temporarily adopted to prevent the audio going to idle is to comment out a section below from the /etc/pulse/default.pa

*### Automatically suspend sinks/sources that become idle for too long*

*#load-module module-suspend-on-idle*

After this, my audio does not go into idling again. I only have to run the script once at login.
My laptop has the facial login, with howdy, i don't have to type in my password when i run the script.
I added the script to my auto-start with ubuntu startup application and my audio works automatically at login with howdy.

Need i also mention that i run kernel-5.13.12-051312-generic.
My audio still works after suspend and hibernation.
I have been able to reproduce this with ubuntu 21.04 + gnome40 desktop only. Had issue on gnome 3.38.
This also works perfectly with ubuntu 21.10 impish development.

I hope someone can make something better out of my discovery and permanently make the audio working seamlessly after installation without tweaking.

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *impish* indri [21.10] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 21.10 is 14 October 2021 (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/impish-indri-release-schedule/18540) when your question will be on-topic here).

Answer (score 0):

Good news!
Just installed Ubuntu 21.10 beta but the sound issue persisted out of the box.
I installed kernel-5.15rc2 and sound started working. Bet a solution at last! Thanks Ubuntu team. Great work.
My spectre 14 ea000 is known to have keyboard delay after each boot. This requires me to consistently tap the keyboard keys randomly until an input is registered at login. It works fine until next reboot.
I resolve this by editing the line below to /etc/default/grub file;
Locate the line,

*GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=" “*

to add *i8042.dumbkbd=1*

This resolves the keyboard delay issue.
Only side effect is that the caps lock key led indicator light does not light up. I now use gnome extension to indicate caps lock state.

Comment: Nice it fixed it for you but a beta product is not really an answer. It may change in so many ways but the time it comes out of beta.